# AngularJS dependancies of variables and $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been trying to understand how Angular does things and can't figure out why $watch doesn't seem to work when a value is assigned to the watched variable. I've boiled it down to this test:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
  testElem={{testElem}}, testData[2]={{testData[2]}}
</div>
```

with

```
function myController($scope){
    $scope.debugFunc= function(){
        $scope.testData=[4,5,6,7,8];
        $scope.$apply();
    };
    setTimeout( $scope.debugFunc, 1000 );

    $scope.testData=[1,2,3];
    $scope.testElem=0;
    $scope.$watch('$scope.testData', 
                  function(){$scope.testElem=$scope.testData[2];}, 
                  true);    
}
```

this outputs `testElem=3, testData[2]=3` then `testElem=3, testData[2]=6`

I notice the watch function is executed at least once since testElem==3, but why not after the assignment of testData[] a second later ?

Comment: For information: (esp. to whoever -voted the question), the incorrect use of "$watch($scope.var" is actually copied from an example in the AngularJS book by Brad Green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$scope.$watch('testData',function(){$scope.testElem=$scope.testData[2];});
```

you don't need to type `$scope` inside `$watch` function

also, since you are watching just an array filled with numbers (values, not references), you can ommit the third parameter in `$watch` function

Comment: That's great - Thanks! (I'm not going to admit how long I've been messing with this ;)